# How do I reverse sort a slice of integer Go?

Tags: go

I am trying to reverse-sort a slice of integers in Go.

```
  example := []int{1,25,3,5,4}
  sort.Ints(example) // this will give me a slice sorted from 1 to the highest number
```

How do I sort it so that it goes from highest to lowest? so [25 5 4 3 1]

I have tried this

```
sort.Sort(sort.Reverse(sort.Ints(keys)))
```

Source: http://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Reverse

However, I am getting the error below

```
# command-line-arguments
./Roman_Numerals.go:31: sort.Ints(keys) used as value
```

Answer (score 102, accepted):

[sort.Ints](http://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Ints) is a convenient function to sort a couple of ints. Generally you need to implement the [sort.Interface](http://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Interface) interface if you want to sort something and [sort.Reverse](http://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Reverse) just returns a different implementation of that interface that redefines the `Less` method.

Luckily the sort package contains a predefined type called [IntSlice](http://golang.org/pkg/sort/#IntSlice) that implements sort.Interface:

```
keys := []int{3, 2, 8, 1}
sort.Sort(sort.Reverse(sort.IntSlice(keys)))
fmt.Println(keys)
```

Comment: IMHO, what is really confusing is `sort.Slice` sorts the list, but `sort.IntSlice` **doesn't** sort it. Instead, we should use `sort.Ints`.

Answer (score 9):

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "sort"
)

func main() {
        example := []int{1, 25, 3, 5, 4}
        sort.Sort(sort.Reverse(sort.IntSlice(example)))
        fmt.Println(example)
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/WTgm8YyZ2N)

---

Output:

```
[25 5 4 3 1]
```

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using two function calls and a cast, you can do it with just `sort.Slice`:

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "sort"
)

func main() {
   example := []int{1,25,3,5,4}
   sort.Slice(example, func(a, b int) bool {
      return example[b] < example[a]
   })
   fmt.Println(example)
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/sort#Slice