# How do I reverse an array in Go?

Tags: go

http://play.golang.org/p/W70J4GU7nA

```
  s := []int{5, 2, 6, 3, 1, 4}
  sort.Reverse(sort.IntSlice(s))
  fmt.Println(s)
  // 5, 2, 6, 3, 1, 4
```

It is hard to understand what it means in func Reverse(data Interface) Interface .

How do I reverse an array? I do not need to sort.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18343208/how-to-reverse-sort-a-slice-of-integer-golang. I think you need to use `Sort` to do it easily.

Comment: This makes me want to throw go out the window. Seriously, I need a loop to reverse an array? The odds of me writing that incorrectly in the first attempt because of an offset-by-one error are astronomical. The code is more verbose and harder to read. And the accepted answer sorts the array, even when OP explicitly says no need to sort.

Comment: This is described on the wiki: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks#reversing

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Normally, to sort an array of integers you wrap them in an `IntSlice`, which defines the methods `Len`, `Less`, and `Swap`. These methods are in turn used by `sort.Sort`. What `sort.Reverse` does is that it takes an existing type that defines `Len`, `Less`, and `Swap`, but it replaces the `Less` method with a new one that is always the inverse of the underlying `Less`:

```
type reverse struct {
    // This embedded Interface permits Reverse to use the methods of
    // another Interface implementation.
    Interface
}

// Less returns the opposite of the embedded implementation's Less method.
func (r reverse) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return r.Interface.Less(j, i)
}

// Reverse returns the reverse order for data.
func Reverse(data Interface) Interface {
    return &reverse{data}
}
```

So when you write `sort.Reverse(sort.IntSlice(s))`, whats happening is that you're getting this new, 'modified' `IntSlice` that has it's `Less` method replaced. So if you call `sort.Sort` on it, which calls `Less`, it will get sorted in decreasing order.

Comment: But, but, but, this also *sorts* the array, doesn't it? The OP *explicity* said he didn't want to sort the array, only reverse it. How can this be the accepted answer?

Answer (score 162):

Honestly this one is simple enough that I'd just write it out like this:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    s := []int{5, 2, 6, 3, 1, 4}

    for i, j := 0, len(s)-1; i < j; i, j = i+1, j-1 {
        s[i], s[j] = s[j], s[i]
    }

    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/vkJg_D1yUb

(The other answers do a good job of explaining `sort.Interface` and how to use it; so I won't repeat that.)

Answer (score 21):

I'm 2 years late, but just for fun and interest I'd like to contribute an "oddball" solution.

Assuming the task really is to reverse a list, then for raw performance [bgp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/961810/bgp)'s solution is probably unbeatable. It gets the job done simply and effectively by swapping array items front to back, an operation that's efficient in the random-access structure of arrays and slices.

In Functional Programming languages, the idiomatic approach would often involve recursion. This looks a bit strange in Go and will have atrocious performance. That said, here's a recursive array reversal function (in a little test program):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    myInts := []int{ 8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9 }
    fmt.Printf("Ints %v reversed: %v\n", myInts, reverseInts(myInts))
}

func reverseInts(input []int) []int {
    if len(input) == 0 {
        return input
    }
    return append(reverseInts(input[1:]), input[0]) 
}
```

Output:

```
Ints [8 6 7 5 3 0 9] reversed: [9 0 3 5 7 6 8]
```

Again, this is for fun and not production. Not only is it slow, but it will overflow the stack if the list is too large. I just tested, and it will reverse a list of 1 million `int`s but crashes on 10 million.

Comment: For the curious, there's only limited TCO in Go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102675/tail-call-optimization-in-go

Comment: FP style +1. Also FP likes expressions not statements. With an `if` use an `else`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63762078/12817546 and "Functional Programming, Simplified".

Comment: Similar but without recursion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72986510/463758

Answer (score 18):

First of all, if you want to reverse the array, do like this,

```
for i, j := 0, len(a)-1; i < j; i, j = i+1, j-1 {
    a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]
}
```

Then, look at the usage of Reverse in golang.org

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

func main() {
    s := []int{5, 2, 6, 3, 1, 4} // unsorted
    sort.Sort(sort.Reverse(sort.IntSlice(s)))
    fmt.Println(s)
}

// output
// [6 5 4 3 2 1]
```

And look at the description of Reverse and Sort

```
func Reverse(data Interface) Interface
func Sort(data Interface)
```

> Sort sorts data. It makes one call to data.Len to determine n, and O(n*log(n)) calls to data.Less and data.Swap. The sort is not guaranteed to be stable.

**So, as you know, Sort is not just a sort algorithm, you can view it as a factory, when you use Reverse it just return a reversed sort algorithm, Sort is just doing the sorting.**

Comment: You probably should only iterate to the mid point of the array: https://play.golang.org/p/JeSApt80_k

Answer (score 7):

This is a more generic slice reverse function. It will panic if input is not a slice.

```
//panic if s is not a slice
func ReverseSlice(s interface{}) {
    size := reflect.ValueOf(s).Len()
    swap := reflect.Swapper(s)
    for i, j := 0, size-1; i < j; i, j = i+1, j-1 {
        swap(i, j)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to reverse the array, you can just go through it in reverse order. Since there is no "reverse range" primitive in the language (at least not yet), you must do something like this (http://play.golang.org/p/AhvAfMjs_7):

```
s := []int{5, 2, 6, 3, 1, 4}
for i := len(s) - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
    fmt.Print(s[i])
    if i > 0 {
        fmt.Print(", ")
    }
}
fmt.Println()
```

Regarding whether it is hard to understand what `sort.Reverse(data Interface) Interface` does, I thought the same until I saw the source code from "http://golang.org/src/pkg/sort/sort.go".

It just makes the comparisons required for the sorting to be made "the other way around".

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple Go solution that uses an efficient (no extra memory) approach to reverse an array:

```
i := 0
j := len(nums) - 1
for i < j {
    nums[i], nums[j] = nums[j], nums[i]
    i++
    j--
}
```

The idea is that reversing an array is equivalent to swapping each element with its mirror image across the center.

https://play.golang.org/p/kLFpom4LH0g

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way to do it

```
func main() {
    example := []int{1, 25, 3, 5, 4}
    sort.SliceStable(example, func(i, j int) bool {
        return true
    })
    fmt.Println(example)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/-tIzPX2Ds9z

Comment: I think this is not the correct way, I've not been able to find a reason, but the below slice does not get reversed []int{48,44,37,40,14,45,8,38,12,31} Which is a little weird.

Comment: @nJoshi if you use `sort.SliceStable` then your array gets reversed. The answer should be updated to use `sort.SliceStable`

Comment: What I am not able to understand even with stable sort is that the order is not guaranteed in cases of equality conditions. The example that @nJoshi provided has all elements unique. This is from the godoc : SliceStable sorts the provided slice given the provided less function while keeping the original order of equal elements.

Comment: i cant tell if this wrong or not. https://play.golang.org/p/wNuwvvpdxMu

Answer (score 2):

```
func Reverse(data Interface) Interface
```

This means that it takes a `sort.Interface` and returns another `sort.Interface` -- it doesn't actually doing any sorting itself. For example, if you pass in `sort.IntSlice` (which is essentially a `[]int` that can be passed to `sort.Sort` to sort it in ascending order) you'll get a new `sort.Interface` which sorts the ints in descending order instead.

By the way, if you click on the function name in [the documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Reverse), it links directly to [the source](http://golang.org/src/pkg/sort/sort.go?s=4988:5026#L205) for `Reverse`. As you can see, it just wraps the `sort.Interface` that you pass in, so the value returned from `Reverse` gets all the methods of the original `sort.Interface`. The only method that's different is the `Less` method which returns the opposite of the `Less` method on the embedded `sort.Interface`. See [this part of the language spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) for details on embedded fields.

Answer (score 1):

From [Golang wiki SliceTricks](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks#reversing):

> To replace the contents of a slice with the same elements but in
>   reverse order:
>
> ```
> for i := len(a)/2-1; i >= 0; i-- {
>   opp := len(a)-1-i
>   a[i], a[opp] = a[opp], a[i]
> }
> ```
>
> The same thing, except with two indices:
>
> ```
> for left, right := 0, len(a)-1; left < right; left, right = left+1, right-1 {
>   a[left], a[right] = a[right], a[left]
> }
> ```

Comment: idk why it was downvoted. it is good to me. And it does a few less operations than `for i, j := 0, len(s)-1; i < j; i, j = i+1, j-1 {`

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution without involving math. Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29440669) solution, this is inefficient as it does too much allocation and garbage collection. Good for non-critical code where clarity is more important than performance. Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/dQGwrc0Q9ZA

```
arr := []int{1, 3, 4, 5, 6}
var rev []int
for _, n := range arr {
    rev = append([]int{n}, rev...)
}
fmt.Println(arr)
fmt.Println(rev)
```

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple if you want to print reverse array

Use Index from length doing i--

ex.

```
a := []int{5, 4, 12, 7, 15, 9}
    for i := 0; i <= len(a)-1; i++ {
        fmt.Println(a[len(a)-(i+1)])
    }
```

https://go.dev/play/p/bmyFh7-_VCZ

Answer (score 1):

Using generic so you can reverse any type arrays

```
func reverseArray[T any](arr []T) []T {
    result := make([]T, len(arr))
    length := len(arr)
    for index := range arr {
        result[(length-1)-index] = arr[index]
    }
    return result
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With go 1.22+, I'd use `slices.Reverse()`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "slices"
)

func main() {

    s := []int{5, 2, 6, 3, 1, 4}

    slices.Reverse(s)

    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/he4pn_5ySq0

Answer (score 0):

To reverse an array in place, iterate to its mid-point, and swap each element with its "mirror element":

```
func main() {
    xs := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
    itemCount := len(xs)
    for i := 0; i < itemCount/2; i++ {
        mirrorIdx := itemCount - i -1
        xs[i], xs[mirrorIdx] = xs[mirrorIdx], xs[i]
    }
    fmt.Printf("xs: %v\n", xs)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/JeSApt80_k

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method using `append`:

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
   a := []int{10, 20, 30, 40, 50}
   for n := len(a) - 2; n >= 0; n-- {
      a = append(a[:n], append(a[n + 1:], a[n])...)
   }
   fmt.Println(a)
}
```

Drawing of the steps:

```
10 20 30 40 50
10 20 30    50 40
10 20       50 40 30
10          50 40 30 20
            50 40 30 20 10
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is mainly for those beginners who wish to write this code using only one variable in the for loop instead of using two variables (like i & j).

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
array := []int{45, 17, 43, 67, 21, 4, 97, 44, 54, 98, 665}
fmt.Println("initial array:", array)
loop_iteration := len(array)
if len(array)%2 == 0 {
    loop_iteration = (len(array) / 2) - 1
  } else {
    loop_iteration = int(len(array) / 2)  //This will give the lower integer value of that float number.
    }
for i := 0; i <= loop_iteration; i++ {
    array[i], array[(len(array)-1)-i] = array[(len(array)-1)-i], array[i]
    }
fmt.Println("reverse array:", array)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://go.dev/play/p/bVp0x7v6Kbs

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    arr := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    fmt.Println(reverseArray(arr))
}

func reverseArray(arr []int) []int {
    reversed := make([]int, len(arr))
    j := 0
    for i := len(arr) - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
        reversed[j] = arr[i]
        j++
    }
    return reversed
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is my [solution](https://play.golang.org/p/hq5PZUWJuN9).

```html
package main

import (
 "fmt"
)

func main() {
 var numbers = [10]int {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
 var reverseNumbers [10]int
 j:=0
 for i:=len(numbers)-1; i>=0 ; i-- {
  reverseNumbers[j]=numbers[i]
  j++ 
 }
 fmt.Println(reverseNumbers)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is my solution to reversing an array:

```golang
func reverse_array(array []string) []string {
    lenx := len(array) // lenx holds the original array length
    reversed_array := make([]string, lenx) // creates a slice that refer to a new array of length lenx

    for i := 0; i < lenx; i++ {
        j := lenx - (i + 1) // j initially holds (lenx - 1) and decreases to 0 while i initially holds 0 and increase to (lenx - 1)
        reversed_array[i] = array[j]
    }

    return reversed_array
}
```

You can try this solution on the go playground [the go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/mGbz2tgQqoa)

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    array := []string{"a", "b", "c", "d"}

    fmt.Println(reverse_array(array)) // prints [d c b a]
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Do not reverse it, leave it as now and then just iterate it backwards.

Comment: Sure you can. But it's faster not reversing it, and just iterating it backwards.

Comment: What if you're passing the slice into something that iterates forwards? Sometimes you have to reverse things.

Comment: Then reverse it :-)