# Idiomatic way to reverse the order of a slice in Go (not sort descending)?

Tags: go

Is there an elegant or idiomatic go way of returning the reverse *order* of a slice? I'm not talking about getting the descending order as was the answer in a similarly asked question here: [How do I reverse sort a slice of integer Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18343208/how-do-i-reverse-sort-a-slice-of-integer-go)

Example, given an array:

```
arr := []int{2, 5, 7, 1}
```

I want a slice with the following output:

```
[1 7 5 2]
```

I know one approach would be to use a for loop but I was wondering if there was a more efficient solution.

Coming from python, one easy and great solution would be using slicing by doing something like:

```
arr[::-1]
```

But go doesn't operate like that so that's why I'm looking for a comparable version of that in go.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there an elegant or idiomatic go way of returning the reverse order of a slice?

No.

You have to switch elements.