# Go sort.IntSlice() Implementation

Tags: sorting, go

I was looking up how to reverse sort a Go array:

```
sort.Sort(sort.Reverse(sort.IntSlice(s))) // s is the slice of ints
```

I checked out the sort pkg for go documentation at https://godoc.org/sort

I see there is a type of IntSlice, but no IntSlice() method for sort package

Can someone explain to how IntSlice() is implementated or why is it not there in the sort pkg?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reverse sort a slice of integer Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18343208/how-do-i-reverse-sort-a-slice-of-integer-go)

Answer (score 0):

So while writing this question out, I looked at type IntSlice source code and realized that IntSlice() is not a function of sort pkg but rather it's an alias for []int so sort.IntSlice(s) turns slice s into type IntSlice.

The reason why we need to convert []int to IntSlice type is because sort.Reverse() requires an Interface type and must implement Len(), Swap(), Less() which []int doesn't implement.

This also reminds me of another point that Donovan & Kernighan wrote regarding interfaces in that we can might not modify concrete types but we can extend functionality via interfaces and it clicked to me that this is an example b/c []int is an underlying type as part of Go language spec but the sort pkg extended behavior via Interface interface.

Comment: The type `sort.IntSlice` is not an [alias](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Alias_declarations) for `[]int`.  The type `sort.IntSlice` has base type `[]int`.